Error: React Fabric - codegen didnot Run propery in your project
I am trying to install react native in my existing ios application since I need to migrate the exsiting application to react native.
I have followed all the steps but getting code
First I have created a simple iOS project then Created a dir in which i created package.json
   {
  "name": "MyReactNativeApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "yarn react-native start"
  }
}


installed Yarn
yarn add react-native - added yarn
yarn add @babel/preset-env && yarn add @babel/core && yarn add react@18.0.0

I have followed all steps mentioned in react native site
gen error.
Refered sites for implemtation -> https://archive.reactnative.dev/docs/integration-with-existing-apps
https://nishabe.medium.com/how-to-integrate-react-native-code-with-an-existing-ios-app-655c61a65b8c
https://fek.io/blog/how-to-add-react-native-to-an-existing-i-os-app-in-2022/
Still getting this error
My xcode version is 15.3

I am facing the same issue and still unable to get any solution. I've tried

removing and re-installing pod
changing the minimum deployment version to 13.0

but the issue still exists.

we faced same error message, and we find out that
echo $REACT_NATIVE_PATH  

outputs into empty string.
You may check React-Fabric in PODS (via XCode) and you can see Build Phase named [CP-User] [RN]Check rncore where IF condition is blocking you:
if [[ ! -d "$rncorePath" ]]; then
  echo 'error: Codegen did not run properly in your project. Please reinstall cocoapods with `bundle exec pod install`.'
  exit 1
fi

Then we ran:
export REACT_NATIVE_PATH=<absolut_path_to_proj>/node_modules/react-native

And everything starts to run :-)
